# set grandchild routing property in spring-data-elastic-search

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm trying to find the way to specify routing property in grandchild creation, as it explained in: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/grandparents.html

```
PUT /company/employee/1?parent=london&routing=uk 
{
    "name":  "Alice Smith",
    "dob":   "1970-10-24",
    "hobby": "hiking"
}
```

However I cannot find this property in spring-data-elastic-search annotations. Anybody has an idea how to specify it?